# Chrome wont use my preloaded audio. It keeps on requesting the same file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, preload

i want to setup a **simple Queue Number calling website** as a terminal. the terminal will poll server to get the latest number to call.

my codes preload 10 simple audios. Then the codes will poll the server each sec to see which file to play sounds through ajax request.

with `Firefox`, the audios get preloaded and each time the server send action to play, the audio will play WITH preloaded file ( no request to the audio file from server )

with `Chrome`, the audios get preloaded initially but each time the server send action to play, the audio will be requested from the server even though it is the same file.

using `angularJS 1.x`

i have test by changing SRC in the audio object, initialize different audio object for each file but Chrome still wont play the cached files. Always request the same file from server

Comment: How do you preload your media? What `cache-control` header does your server send with the request? I personaly can't repro.

Comment: i use embbed tag <audio preload="auto" /> for each my sound files.. in JS i just call back the src URL to the audio object.. this works with Firefox.. but not in chrome

Comment: my server dont send the `cache-control` header

Comment: *embed tag* as in <embed>? Can you set up an [MCVE] please.

Comment: `<audio id="au0" preload="auto"><source src="/QMS/tv/0.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload></audio>`

Answer (score 0):

!SOLVED!

a very silly mistake i have made. Im using PHP built in web server to develop this. so i neglect the http server part.

just a simple .htaccess script on the folder for audio access to send `cache-control` did the trick.

thanks to @Kaiido for the tips